# qsort on an array of pointers to Objective-C objects

Tags: objective-c, qsort

I have an array of pointers to Objective-C objects. These objects have a sort key associated with them. I'm trying to use qsort to sort the array of pointers to these objects. However, the first time my comparator is called, the first argument points to the first element in my array, but the second argument points to garbage, giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to access its sort key.

Here is my code (paraphrased):

```
- (void)foo:(int)numThingies {
    Thingie **array;
    array = malloc(sizeof(deck[0])*numThingies);

    for(int i = 0; i < numThingies; i++) {
        array[i] = [[Thingie alloc] initWithSortKey:(float)random()/RAND_MAX];
    }

    qsort(array[0], numThingies, sizeof(array[0]), thingieCmp);
}

int thingieCmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Thingie *ia = (const Thingie *)a;
    const Thingie *ib = (const Thingie *)b;

    if (ia.sortKey > ib.sortKey) return 1; //ib point to garbage, so ib.sortKey produces the EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    else return -1;
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Have you checked whether `b` is pointing inside the allocated array? Maybe that'll offer a clue.

Comment: why not use NSArray or similar cocoa datastructure to keep track of your Thingies and sort them?

Comment: Sadly, NSArray does not fit my requirements in this *particular* case. See my response to bbum's (excellent) answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is two fold:

- the first argument to qsort needs to be a pointer to the beginning of the array
- the arguments passed to your sort function are actually pointers to the pointers of your data

Consider this working code:

```
int thingieCmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    NSObject *aO = *(NSObject **)a;
    NSObject *bO = *(NSObject **)b;

    if (aO.hash > bO.hash) return 1; 
    else return -1;
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSObject **array;
    array = malloc(sizeof(NSObject*)*20);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        array[i] = [NSObject new];
    }

    qsort(array, 20, sizeof(NSObject*), thingieCmp);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the comparison function resolves the data pointers by `NSObject *aO = *(NSObject **)a` and the `qsort` function takes `array` as an argument directly.

All of this, though, begs the question of ***Why bother?***

`NSArray` is very good at holding arrays of objects and is quite conveniently sortable.  Performance is excellent in the general case.  If performance analysis indicates that it isn't, you can optimize it away relatively easily.

Note, also, that I have been consistent in use of `sizeof()` -- same type in both places.  Also, the `const` in your original code is not necessary.

Comment: Brilliant! Magnificent, sir! Thank you so much!

To answer your question, this is portable engine code that I want to be able to use in future pure C projects (Thingie is going to turn into void momentarily). I used NSArray when I was prototyping, and you're right, it's a wonderful data structure. If only it fit my requirements!

Thanks again. You win at life. :)

(Quick aside: How do I make line breaks in these comments? The two-space trick in the Markdown Editing Help page isn't working.)

Comment: Your welcome!

Line breaks are pretty much a matter of manually formatting the code blocks...

Answer (score 1):

I think, one mistake lies right in the line

```
qsort(array[0], numThingies, sizeof(array[0]), thingieCmp);
```

Try

```
qsort(&array[0], numThingies, sizeof(array[0]), thingieCmp);
```

or even

```
qsort(array, numThingies, sizeof(array[0]), thingieCmp);
```

instead. The compiler won't complain here, as `qsort` is supposed to take a `void*` and you pass it a `Thingy*` which can legally be cast to `void*` without warning, but you really want `qsort` to operate on the entire array, which has type `Thingy**`.

Another thing is: the comparator will be called with pointers to the array slots as arguments, so what you get is actually a `Thingy**`:

```
int 
thingieCmp(void* a, void* b) 
{
    Thingie *ia = *((Thingie**)a);
    Thingie *ib = *((Thingie**)b);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Tried both of those ideas. Both result in /both/ arguments pointing to garbage.

Comment: @ElBueno: What's `deck` in the allocation of the array? Just a typo?

Comment: Typo, yes. I knew I'd miss one. :)